# Microsoft Graph notifications to group membership changes limitations

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We need to track changes to approximately 5,000 Azure AD groups in a tenant. This represents a small subset of total number of AAD groups in the tenant

I'm investigating if Microsoft Graph subscription notifications are suitable for this. From what I have read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#azure-ad-resource-limitations) each tenant only supports up to 1,000 subscription notifications for Azure AD resources.

Can I create 1 subscription to be notified when any AAD group membership is modified? Or can I create a subscription for 5,000+ groups without breaking any limitations?

What if I use Teams resources? The same article implies that the limit for teams resources is 10,000 subscriptions.

Or is there some other mechanism I should consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#azure-ad-resource-limitations) , Maximum subscription quotas:

- Per app (for all tenants combined): 50,000 total subscriptions
- Per tenant (for all applications combined): 1000 total subscriptions across all apps
- Per app and tenant combination: 100 total subscriptions

So if you are trying to create the subscription for 5,000+ groups , for all tenant tenant combined , then its possible ,but its not possible for an App in single tenant .

For you 2nd question ,the limit for teams resources , Each Teams resource has different subscription quotas.

For subscriptions to callRecords:

Per organization: 100 total subscriptions

you can check limits - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#teams-resource-limitations

Hope this helps

Thanks